# Why do we care about PA proving itself consistent?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, incompleteness, nonstandard-models

"No first-order theory containing a sufficient amount of arithmetic can prove its own consistency". It's the "prove its own" part of Godel's theorem that always confused me. Why do we care so much about PA proving $\textit{itself}$ consistent? Can't we prove it is consistent using our natural language?

Now, I am making the rough claim here that $\mathbb{N}$ exists intuitively in our natural language. Since we know that every satisfiable set of axioms is consistent (equivalent to soundness) and $\mathbb{N}$ satisifies the PA axioms, then the existence of $\mathbb{N}$ says that PA is consistent!

Of course there must be something I'm misunderstanding. The only objection to my 'PA-consistency proof' that I can think of is that formalists would claim that our intuition of $\mathbb{N}$ is actually more dubious than finite manipulations of strings. Therefore we should trust the formal manipulation of strings.

But, I would argue that the only reason they trust those finite manipulations of strings is because there are 'proofs' that $\vdash$ corresponds to $\models$ (completeness and soundness). And these two theorems are 'proved' outside of a formal language using our natural language (they are theorems $\textit{about}$ first-order languages, not theorems $\textit{of}$ first-order languages). So shouldn't a formalist think of formalism as being just as dubious as $\mathbb{N}$?

I hope that all made sense. In short, I am asking why can we not just claim that $\mathbb{N}$ proves PA is consistent based on the soundness theorem?

Also, I would be grateful if someone could give me some insights on how other consistency proofs work for other formal theories. In order for them to all prove their own consistency wouldn't they have to use some kind of self-referencing similar to Godel codes?

Comment: Of course, after I posted this I found a question similar to mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120035/consistency-of-pa-why-other-proofs?rq=1.

Comment: The issue is: "to prove consistency of arithmetic" and then also that of analysis; see [Hilbert's second problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_second_problem).

Comment: And see [Hilbert’s Program](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hilbert-program): the research program launched by Hilbert to prove consistency of arithmetic and analysis in a "safe system" that he (Hilbert) imagined to be a **sub-system** of arithmetic itself. The relevance of [G's Th](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) for the original Hilbert's program was that arithmetic was "not enough" to prove arithmetic's consistency, and *a fortiori*, neither sub-systems of arithmetic can do the job. That was the story...

Comment: You can prove that PA is consistent and according to standard mathematical practice your proof is perfectly fine. One can also formalize your proof in a first order theory that can talk about PA and $\mathbb{N}$ (e.g. ZFC). A formalist wouldn't object to this. There's nothing wrong here. The only people that might have an issue are finitists.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Ok, so the reals prove the consistency of analysis by the above argument.

Comment: @Jonathan So if the above proof is satisfactory, barring finitism, then why are there still endless discussions on the implications on Godel's incompleteness theorems?

Comment: @pmac Because it only proves the consistency of PA. ZFC still can't prove its own consistency. You can again go to a stronger system which also proves ZFC consistent and hope that it is consistent. But then again you can't prove that from within that theory. It would be desirable to have one big universal theory where you don't have to step out and make further assumptions to prove its consistency. Gödel's theorem showed that this is impossible for any nice enough theory.

Comment: What difference would a formal proof of consistency of PA make to the work of mathematicians? IIUC propositional logic has been show to be  consistent. What important results if any have emerged from that?

Comment: @Jonathan Ok I think I am starting to get it but I still have some questions. When I say use N to prove ZFC, I don't mean use the ZFC interpretation of N, I mean just use {1,2,3,4...}. Now, I think think the objection to this is that {1,2,3,4...} is not a set in the strict sense. But why are intuitive/naive sets not allowed to be models? Herbrand structures do exactly this.

Comment: Then, for ZFC, can we not just construct the simplest model conceivable (for example Godel's constructible universe) and show that it satisfies ZFC? Or would this technically be claiming  ZFC + V=L $\vdash$ ZFC? If this is the case, I have never seen V=L written as a first order sentence(s).

Comment: "can we not just construct the simplest model conceivable (for example Godel's constructible universe) and show that it satisfies ZFC?" Models of ZFC (assuming they exist in the first place of course) are necessarily extremely complicated; for example, [ZFC has no computable models](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12426/is-there-a-computable-model-of-zfc), no *hyperarithmetic* $\omega$-models, and the situation with transitive models is even worse. And even if we "had a model of ZFC," we would still need to verify that it satisfied the (infinitely many, increasingly complicated) ZFC axioms.

Comment: Separately, I think it's worth challenging your framing of the motivation of the second incompleteness theorem. There are entirely non-philosophical reasons to care: in general, the second incompleteness theorem is a frequently-used tool in proving that a given sentence is independent of PA (e.g. Paris-Harrington). So from a purely mathematical standpoint, if we want to understand what PA does and doesn't prove, the second incompleteness theorem is a good thing to have.